# Woocommerce checkout page text for Paypal

Tags: css, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, checkout

I'm running woocommerce under the wootique wordpress theme. [Here's a link to my site](http://www.switch-witch.com/checkout/).

Since Paypal is the only payment processor, I wanted the text under the paypal button to be more 'prominent'. Bigger font size, maybe a different colour.

I tried adding the following code to my CSS, but that didn't change anything, even with the !important tag:

```
#payment .payment_box p {
font-size:16px; 
color: #ee4122;
}
```

According to Firefox that is the right element and even editing the ul.payment_methods .payment_box p directly in my theme's style.css doesn't change anything.

I seem to be stuck. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could take a quick look (you may have to add the item to your cart for the checkout page to show up properly!)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.payment_methods .payment_box p {
font-size:16px; 
color: #ee4122;
}
```

This works for me. I do know that caching plugins can cause items to not visually update right away so you have to clear the cache from WP (not necessarily just your browser). I can see your other code in your stylesheet and it is applying (the margin on the `ul.payment_methods .payment_box p`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to clear the cache from WP? I have W3 Total Cache and ran it but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried different browsers and they all show the same black text as before. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Go to the Performance menu (W3 Total Cache Settings) and then click "Empty all cache" (it's a button).

Comment: You want to consider using the [PayPal for WooCommerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).  It's free and provides Express Checkout which streamlines the checkout flow and makes guest checkout (credit cards) much more prominent so people don't think they need PayPal, which seems to be what your main goal here.  There are lots of other advantages of Express Checkout, too.